# Creating label in leaflet map using htmltools produces tiny label

Tags: html, r, leaflet

Creating a leaflet map. First step, specify the label. The code used on leaflet github puts

```
%>% lapply(htmltool::HTML)
```

after the sprintf() function. However, making it is creating the label as a type:"list" resulting in the error: "Error in sum(sapply(label, function(x) { : invalid 'type' (list) of argument"

So to try and get around this I just load the htmltools library and use the code

```
HTML(sprintf(...))
```

Doing this works and runs the map, however, the labels show up as small boxes with no information (see picture link below)

I can't tell if this is something to do with the code inside sprintf() or if this has to do with HTML().

The weird thing is that the %>% lapply method was working just fine, but something happened and now its giving the error mentioned above

[Image with the small label shown as little white box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5aNf.jpg)

```
labels.dest2 <- sprintf("<div style = 'overflow-wrap: anywhere;'><strong>%s <br/>%s Destinations</div><br/>%s Euclidean Miles from LAX on average<br/>%s minutes between OD tweets </div><br/>%s Miles from LAX on average</div><br/>%s minutes from LAX on average</div>",
                  puma.spdf$NAME,
                  puma.spdf$Dest_pt_count,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_Euc_Dist_Mi,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_tweetTime,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_RtDist_Mi,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_RtTime_min) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% etc...
```

FULL CODE HERE

```
## Map with OD data and travel stats  ##

labels.dest2 <- HTML(sprintf("<div style = 'overflow-wrap: anywhere;'> <strong>%s <br/>%g Destinations</div><br/>%s Euclidean Miles from LAX on average<br/>%s minutes between OD tweets </div><br/>%s Miles from LAX on average</div><br/>%s minutes from LAX on average</div>",
                  puma.spdf$NAME,
                  puma.spdf$Dest_pt_count,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_Euc_Dist_Mi,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_tweetTime,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_RtDist_Mi,
                  puma.spdf$Avg_RtTime_min))

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng=-118.243683, lat=34.1, zoom  = 9.35) %>%
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon="fa-crosshairs", title = "Default View", 
    onClick=JS("function(btn, map) {var groupLayer = map.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Destinations (red)'); map.fitBounds(groupLayer.getBounds());}")))  %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron, 
                   group = "Grey") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite, 
                   group = "OSM")  %>%

  # Add Polygons
  # Destination data
    addPolygons(data = puma.spdf,
              group = "Destination Density",
              fillColor = ~pal.dest(Dest_pt_count),
              weight = 1,
              opacity = 90,
              color = "white",
              dashArray = "3",
              fillOpacity = 0.5,
              highlight = highlightOptions(weight = 2,
                                           color = "#666",
                                           dashArray = "",
                                           fillOpacity = 0.7,
                                           bringToFront = TRUE,
                                           sendToBack = TRUE),
              label = labels.dest2,
              labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                                          textsize = "15px",
                                          direction = "auto")) %>%
  addLegend(values=puma.spdf$Dest_pt_count,
            group = "Destination Density",
            pal=pal.dest,
            title="Destination Density (Dest per PUMA)", 
            position = "bottomright") %>%

   # Add Points
  addCircleMarkers(data = D.spdf, 
                   radius = 2,
                   color = "red",
                   group = "Destinations (red)",
                   fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = O.spdf, 
                   radius = 2,
                   color = "green",
                   group = "Origins (green)") %>%

  # Add Layer Controls
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Grey"),
    overlayGroups = c("Destinations (red)", "Origins (green)","Destination Density"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the first column puma.spdf$NAME was not part of the dataset and was throwing off the string.. check to make sure all the variables you want to show are actually part of the dataset.